# C/C++ equivalent to Bash "readlink -f"

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

I'm coding a Linux tool in C/C++ and receive a full path to a directory as input, this will always be rooted at "/" but elements of the path may be symlinks rather than real directories. For example:
/tools/sometool/latest
where "latest" is a symlink to "1.0".

The path is then used to filter a list of other files. My problem is that the other files can use either form:
/tools/sometool/latest/foo.txt
/tools/sometool/1.0/foo.txt
and I need to treat both as matching the criteria of being contained inside /tools/sometool/latest. I therefore need a way to fully resolve all the symlinks in the path.

In Bash, "readlink -f /tools/sometool/latest" returns "/tools/sometool/1.0" which is perfect, but when I try "readlink()" in C, it just gives me "1.0".
I've searched but can't find any existing solution to this in C.
Is there a simple solution that I've missed, or do I need to build the equivalent of the bash command in C to make this work?

Thanks!

P.S. The tool doesn't need to be portable, so a Linux-only solution would be fine.

Comment: How about using [`dirname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) to get the directory, and then append the result from `readlink`? Or use [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (or [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) if you don't have `std::filesystem`) for a C++ solution?

Comment: What is C/C++? Do you mean C++?

Comment: By C/C++, I was alluding to the fact that I am happy to use either a "native" C++ library solution if one exists, or a low-level C one, as I already have to use some low-level C calls like regexp and stat anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `realpath()` (see [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)). This does basically the same as `readlink -f`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++17, you can try [std::filesystem::canonical](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical).

> Converts path p to a canonical absolute path, i.e. an absolute path that has no dot, dot-dot elements or *symbolic links* in its generic format representation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    fs::path p = fs::path("/tools/sometool/latest");
    std::cout << "Canonical path for " << p << " is " << fs::canonical(p) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I'm stuck on gcc 4.8 so I don't think C++17 is an option, but it's a good tip anyway :)